# How to stop re-rendering when using useContext (Reactjs)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer, use-context

I have a simple react app in which there is a **FruitsList** component for showing the fruits in the list, a **FruitForm** component to add a fruit, and both are contained inside a **Fruits** component. I am using `useContext` and `useReducer` to manage the state of the fruits. I have created a **FruitContext** for same. I want to stop the re-rendering of **FruitForm** since it is only using dispatch function and re-rendering it is useless every time new fruit is added. Plz suggest any solution for same.

**Form Component**

```
const Form = () => {

  const { dispatch } = useContext(FruitsContext);
  const { setLoading } = useContext(LoaderContext);

  let formRef = null;
  const fruit = {};

  const formSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setLoading(true);
      await fetch('https://fruit-basket-74269.firebaseio.com/fruits.json', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(fruit)
        });
        dispatch({type: 'ADD', fruit: fruit});
        // formRef.reset();
        setLoading(false);
      }

      return (
        <Card>
          {console.log('[Form]')}
          <form ref={ref => formRef = ref} onSubmit={formSubmitHandler} className={style.form} autoComplete="off">
            <div className={style.formGroup}>
              <input onChange={event => fruit.item = event.target.value} className={style.input} type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter fruit name" />
              <label className={style.label} htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className={style.formGroup}>
              <input onChange={event => fruit.qty = event.target.value} className={style.input} type="number" min="0" id="qty" placeholder="Enter quantity" />
              <label className={style.label} htmlFor="qty">Quantity</label>
            </div>
            <Button>Add Fruit</Button>
          </form>
        </Card>
      )
}

export default React.memo(Form);
```

**FruitList**

```
const FruitList = () => {

  const { fruits } = useContext(FruitsContext);
  console.log('[FruitList]:', fruits);

  return useMemo(() => {

    return (
      <div className={style.fruitList}>
        <h2 className={style.heading}>Fruits</h2>
        <hr />
        <div className={style.list}>
          <FruitCard name={'Apple'} qty={15} />
          <FruitCard name={'Orange'} qty={10} />
          <FruitCard name={'Grapes'} qty={20} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }, []);
}

export default FruitList;
```

**Fruits**

```
const Fruits = () => {

  console.log('[Fruits Parent]');

  // const { loading } = useContext(LoaderContext);

  return (
    <div className={style.fruits}>
      {/* {loading && <Loader />} */}
      <Form />
      <br />
      <Filter />
      <br />
      <FruitList />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Fruits
```

**FruitContext**

```
export const FruitsContext = createContext();

const FruitsProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [fruits, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  const value = ({
    fruits, dispatch
  });

  return (
    <FruitsContext.Provider value={value}>
      { children }
    </FruitsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default FruitsProvider;
```

**FruitReducer**

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'LOAD':
      return action.fruits
    case 'ADD':
      console.log('[Pre-Action]', state);
      const newList = [...state];
      newList.push(action.fruit);
      console.log('[Post-Action]', newList);
      return newList;
    case 'DELETE':
      return state.filter(fruit => fruit.id !== action.id);
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show a minimal working code

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: What form plugin are you using? If formik try FastField: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fastfield

Comment: I have added the code for same

Comment: No I am not using any form plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components that consume a context will always rerender if anything in the providers value changed. Regardless of whether you actually use that value or not (In this case for example even if you only pull the dispatch function).

Usually you don't need to optimize something like that for most react applications, react is already quite fast and a few additional rerenders don't hurt. Any performance issues can be solved when and where they happen.
If you want to optimize from the start you can split your reducers state and dispatch into two different contexts. They both can be put into the same ProviderComponent but there have to be two different Context.Provider components. One will use the state as value and the other will use the dispatch function as value.
If you then consume the dispatch context, it won't cause the component to rerender if the dispatch action changes the state.

// Update

As an example:

```
const FruitsProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [fruits, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  return (
    <FruitsStateContext.Provider value={fruits}>
      <FruitsDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        { children }
      </FruitsDispatchContext.Provider>
    </FruitsStateContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I would also recommend to not export the context directly but instead export hooks that expose the state or the dispatch.

e.g.

```
export const useFruits = () => {
  const fruitsState = React.useContext(FruitsStateContext);
  if (!fruitsState) {
    throw new Error('you cant use the useFruits hook outside the FruitsStateContext');
  }
  return fruitsState;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but instead of splitting contexts, can't we just use React.memo or useMemo to stop re-renderig

Comment: Sure, you can do that, too but using useMemo in my experience often causes unintended bugs because you might miss some dependencies sometimes.

Using React.memo is usually the best option but probably won't help much here, as it will still rerender since it's basically a state change. But you can prevent components further down to rerender with that.

Depending on how many components are affected I would still try to split the providers.

And still: Above all else - If you don't face any performance issues I don't see the need to do any optimization there anyways.